# Fade in and fade out elements with hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with a menu. If the user moves the cursor over principal elements of the menu, it shows a sub-menu (it has a delay to hide), but if I move the cursor over another principal element, the previous element is still showing behind the new element (and is only hide passing the delay).

How can hide the previous element when I pass the cursor over another principal element?

Below is the menu:

```js
$('li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn(100);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(1000).fadeOut(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav ref">
  <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option">
    <a id="drop-to" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle firstTextOption">P element</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row change-f">
      <li class="col-sm-4 option-sm">
        <ul>
          <li> </li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
          <li> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option">
    <a id="drop-to" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle firstTextOption">P element</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row change-f">
      <li class="col-sm-4 option-sm">
        <ul>
          <li> </li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It'd really help if you'd add a fiddle (:

Comment: You don't need a fiddle; this code can execute from a Stack snippet. I've formatted the code and put it into one of those :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you, I need to learn about how can I do these!

Comment: if you have mouseover you can add mouseout, $(document).on('mouseover', 'li.dropdown', function() {//your codes}); $(document).on('mouseout', 'li.dropdown', function() {// your codes});

Comment: @victor -- No problem, and you can add your own by clicking the code icon (next to the picture icon) when creating or editing a question. You can then automatically format the code by hitting the `Tidy` button. You can find more info on formatting [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I changed your second menu id to #drop-two.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu2').hide();
   
  $('#drop-to').mouseover(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn();
  })
  
  $('#drop-to').mouseout(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut(1000);
  })
  
  $('#drop-two').mouseover(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu2').fadeIn();
  })
 
    $('#drop-two').mouseout(function() {
  $('.dropdown-menu2').fadeOut(1000);
  })
  

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav ref">
  <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option">
    <a id="drop-to" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle firstTextOption">P element</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-large row change-f">
      <li class="col-sm-4 option-sm">
        <ul>
          <li> </li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
          <li> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown dropdown-large option">
    <a id="drop-two" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle firstTextOption">P element</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu2 dropdown-menu-large row change-f">
      <li class="col-sm-4 option-sm">
        <ul>
          <li> </li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header title"><a href="#">subelement</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I used hide() and show(), but it works with fadeIn() and fadeOut() too.

Comment: The problem here is if I move the cursor to another element automatically the submenu will hidding and i want that the submenu wait an specific time to hide

Comment: I changed my code a little bit. Is that more like what you're looking for?

Comment: Im sorry but not, check my code and yo can see how the elements are displayed